# Mostrar Datos de mongodb en motor de plantilla PUG

Tags: nodejs, mongoose, crud, pug

estoy atascado en un problema con pug, tengo un backend, ya he hecho todas las pruebas CRUD en Postman y funcionan perfectamente, instale pug para mostrar los datos, hice un formulario para insertar datos a la BD y funciona perfectamente, pero a la hora de listarlos no puedo hacer que se muestren en pantalla, ya he intentado las iteraciones que vienen en la documentación y nada,
si alguien puede echarme la mano por favor, adjunto mi repositorio,
Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

https://github.com/danielCamachoPerez/admin_receta.git

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, incluye el código relevante a tu pregunta dentro de la pregunta. La idea es que le sirva a otros en el futuro y, si borras el repo, el usuario o cambias el proyecto, ya la pregunta deja de servirle a los demás. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 1):

En el archivo recetas.pug la direccion esta incorrecta, la direccion correcta es:

```
section.section
  .buttons
    a.button.is-primary(href='/receta/listar') verRecetas
```

la misma que usa postman para mostrar resultados